# Numbers of zero of a function with parameter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, roots

> $$f(x) = x^3 - 9bx^2 + 3$$

How many zeroes has this function, depending on real $b$?

I don't really know if this is a tricky question or not. I mean, I have a cubic equation: $x^3 - 9bx^2 + 3 = 0$
hence, I expect, in $\mathbb{C}$ three solutions. That is, three zeroes.

This is trivial.

But let's suppose it's not that tricky and it asks me when I have REAL zeroes, considering the changing of $b$.

How could I reason in this case? Either I can hvae three distinct real roots or just one. How to understand when a case and when the other?

Consider that my math level reaches limits and derivatives, so no advanced methods.

Comment: I think, the discriminant of this cubic is $243(36b^3-1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to study your function in another way. Let's do the following:

$$x^3 - 9bx^2 + 3 = 0 \longrightarrow x^3 + 3 = 9bx^2 \longrightarrow \underbrace{\dfrac{x^3+3}{9x^2}}_{f(x)} = b$$

with $x\neq 0$. Then the domain reads $\Omega: x\in (-\infty, 0)\cup (0, +\infty)$

We then need to study $f(x)$ in a very rapid way. We notice that

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$$

Also

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x) = $$

To calculate this limit, we choose a sequence $x_n = -\frac{1}{n}$ such that $x_n \to 0^-$ as $n\to +\infty$ and $x_n \neq 0^-$ (using Heine definition of limits). For example choosing $x_n = -\frac{1}{n}$ we easily show

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} \dfrac{-\frac{1}{n^3} + 3}{\frac{9}{n^2}} \to +\infty$$

You can prove this by choosing another sequence like $x_n = -e^{-n}$.

In a similar way, but with $0^+$ you prove the limit goes to $+\infty$.

This is useful for the graph and for the analysis.

Now the derivative reads

$$f'(x) = \frac{x^3-6}{9x^3}$$

Which is zero ar $x = \sqrt[3]{6}$

Also studying the sign we get

$$f'(x) > 0 \qquad \qquad x\in(-\infty, 0) \cup (\sqrt[3]{6}, +\infty)$$

With all those information, it's rather easy to sketch an effective graph for this function, try it.

You will see now that $f(x) = b$ means: where does a horizontal straight line of equation $y = b$ intersects $f(x)$?

Well it's easily done.

If $b = f(\sqrt[3]{6})$ then there are exactly two real solutions, for that point represents a local minimum for the function.

If $b > f(\sqrt[3]{6})$ then there are three real roots.

If $b < f(\sqrt[3]{6})$ then there is one real root.

Comment: This looks clearer.

Answer (score 2):

The equation admits one real solution for $b=0.$ We will study the case $b\neq 0.$ We have $$f'(x)=3(x^2-6bx)=3x(x-6b)$$ There are two stationary points $x=0$ and $x=6b.$  $$f(0)=3,\quad f(6b)=3(1- 6^2b^3)$$ Assume $b>0.$ The function is increasing for $x<0$, decreasing in $(0,6b)$ and increasing in $(6b,\infty).$ Therefore the function admits a local maximum at $0$ and a local minimum at $6b.$ As the value at $0$ is positive there is one negative solution by the intermediate value property. If the value at $6b$ is positive then the function is positive for $x>0.$ Thus the equation has one real solution iff $1-6^2b^3>0.$ If $f(6b)=0$ the function is positive for $0<x<6b$ and for $x>6b.$ Therefore there are two  solutions iff $1-6^2b^3=0.$ If $f(6b)<0$ by the intermediate value property we have one solution in $(0,6b)$ and one solution in $(6b,\infty).$ Hence there are three real solutions iff $1-6^2b^3<0.$

Let $b<0.$ Then the function is increasing in $(-\infty,6b)$, decreasing in $(6b,0)$and increasing in $(0,\infty).$ Thus it admits a local maximum at $6b$ and a local minimum at $0.$ As the value at $0$ is positive the equation admits one real solution.

Summarizing we have one real solution for $b<{1\over 6^{2/3}},$ two real solutions for $b={1\over 6^{2/3}}$ and three real solutions for $b> 
 {1\over 6^{2/3}}.$

Comment: "Therefore the equation has one real solution iff $1-6^2b^2>0,$ two real solutions iff $1-6^2b^2=1$  and three real solutions iff $1-6^2b^2<0.$" Forgive me, I don't understand why...

Comment: I have re-edited. Hopefully it is clearer now. Try to imagine the graph of the function for $b\neq 0.$ It starts at $-\infty$ and ends at $\infty.$ On the way it  admits extreme points: first maximum and then minimum. The number of roots depends on the value at the minimum. If it is positive there is just one root. If it is $0$ we get two roots. If it is negative we get three roots.

Comment: You may want to check your expression for $ \ f(6b) \  ; \ $ the critical value of the parameter $ \ b \ $ is incorrect.

Comment: @boojum Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of investigating questions about the real zeroes of a polynomial is to start by neglecting the constant term and just considering the "shape" of the curve. We already see from the Rule of Signs that $ f(x) \ = \ x^3 - 9bx^2 + 3 \ $ has either two or no positive real zeroes for $ \ b \ > \ 0 \ $ and no positive real zeroes for $ \ b \ < \ 0 \ \ ; \ $ there is one negative real zero in either case.  "Removing" the constant term produces $ \  g(x) \ = \ x^3 - 9bx^2 \ = \ x^2·(x - 9b) \ \ , \ $  which always has a "double zero" at $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ and a third zero at $ \ x \ = \ 9b \ \ . \ $  The first two derivatives of this modified function, and of $ \ f(x) \ \   $ as well, are $ \ g'(x) \ = \ 3x^2 - 18bx \ = \ 3x·(x - 6b) \ $ and $ \ g''(x) \ = \ 6x - 18b \ = \ 6·(x - 3b) \ \ . \ $  Thus, the relative extrema are always found at $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ and $ \ x \ = \ 6b \ \ , \ $ with the point of inflection midway between them at $ \ x \ = \ 3b \ \  $ (as expected for a cubic polynomial).

We find from the foregoing that $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ is a double zero of $ \ g(x) \ $, except for $ \ b \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ when it becomes a *triple* zero (and the inflection point of the curve); it is the relative maximum for $ \ b \ < \ 0 \ $ and the relative minimum for $ \ b \ > \ 0 \ \ . \ $  If we now "vertically shift" the curve "upward" by $ \ 3 \ $ units to obtain one for $ \ f(x) \ \ , \ $ we can characterize the "behavior" of our function for the main cases:

• for $ \ b \ < \ 0 \ \ , \ $ the relative *maximum* is located at $ \ ( \ 6b \ , \ [6b]^2·[-3b] \ + \ 3 \ > \ 0 \ ) \ $ and the relative minimum is at the $ \ y-$intercept $ \ ( \ 0 \ , \ 3  \ ) \ \ ; \ $ thus, for this case, $ \ f(x) \ $ has only one negative real zero;

• for $ \ b \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ $ there is of course only the single real zero at $ \ x \ = \ -\sqrt[3]{3} \ \ ; $

• for $ \ b \ > \ 0 \ \ , \ $ the relative *maximum* is located at  the $ \ y-$intercept $ \ ( \ 0 \ , \ 3  \ )  $ and the relative *minimum* at $  \ ( \ 6b \ , \ [6b]^2·[-3b] \ + \ 3 \ = \ 3 - 108b^3 \  ) \ . $

It is this third case in which a complication appears.  We note that there is a "critical" value of $ \ b \ $ at which the relative minimum will lie on the $ \ x-$axis, given by $ \ 3 - 108b_{crit}^3 \ = \ 0 \ $ $ \Rightarrow \ b_{crit} \ = \ \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{36}} \ \approx \ 0.3029 \ . \ $  So there are three "subcases" to be remarked upon here:

• for $ \ 0 \ < \ b \ < \ b_{crit} \ \ , \ $ the relative minimum value of $ \ f(x) \ $ is positive, so the function has just one negative real zero;

• for $ \  b \ = \ b_{crit} \ \ , \ $ the relative minimum value of $ \ f(x) \ $ is a double zero at $ \ x \ = \  6 b_{crit} \ = \ \sqrt[3]{6} \ \approx \ 1.817 \ \ , \  $ along with the negative real zero, which can readily be determined *exactly* [the polynomial becomes $ \ x^3 \ - \ \sqrt[3]{\frac{81}{4}}·x^2 \ + \ 3 \ \approx \ x^3 \ - \ 2.7257·x^2 \ + \ 3 \ \ , \ $ which factors as $ \ (x - \sqrt[3]{6})^2 · \left(x + \sqrt[3]{\frac34} \right) \ \ . \ ] \ ;$

• for $ \  b \ > \ b_{crit} \ \ , \ $ the relative minimum value of $ \ f(x) \ $ is *negative*, so $ \ f(x) \ $ will have two positive real zeroes, in addition to the negative real zero. (So the "promise" of the Rule of Signs is fulfilled.)